# Eclipse RCP -- Open View in Editor folder

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

Is it possible to add placeholders in the editor folder stack?

I can currently move my views (drag-n-drop) next to an editor, but I want them to be opened directly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using eclipse 3.x, it is not possible. With 4.x should be possible (since Eclipse 4 no longer has an editor area, which must be defined for a perspective, so that you can also put editors in a ViewStack.). You may find something useful in [Vogella's article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html).

Comment: It's a 3.x app on top of Kepler. I don't use e4xmi Application Models. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Changing Eclipse presentation layer. However, you need a lot of effort to do so. To start with something, please refer to this short article http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel

Comment: Lots of deprecated stuff there. I'll just go with an e4 hybrid.

Comment: @GGrec do you have an answer to your question? if so can you post it?

Comment: @janh This is not possible with 3.x applications. You'll have to take up on e4.