# Eclipse RCP - Open a View in the Editor Area (3.8/e4 hybrid)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-luna, e4

I'm working on a 3.8-e4 hybrid (i.e we have the Luna dependencies, but we **do not** use the *Application.e4xmi*, yet). So we're basically running the compact layer.

With that being said, it would be nice to find an e4 programmatic way to stack these nasty views onto the editor folder.

---

### 1.) Problem

I want to place a generic view folder in the editor area, so that each view which is opened at runtime will be opened there.

[image: View in editor folder]

*(pic stolen from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758642/eclipse-rcp-stacking-a-view-with-the-editor-area))*

---

### 2.1) Possible fix no.1: Using plugin.xml

Create a perspective extension, and add each possible view to that extension, with **relationship stack** over **relative org.eclipse.ui.editorss**. This is a bit inconvenient if you have too many views awating to be opened, and if the project scales quickly. I also noticed that wildcard view IDs do not work here.

[image: SS of the plugin.xml with perspective extensions]

If you find yourself the time to add each possible view to the perspective extension, that would work. Although, IF you open a view which is not added here (ie: opens in a different folder), then each subsequent opened view will be opened in the previous folder, and NOT in the editor area (inquire further explanation if you don't get it).

---

### 2.2) Possible fix no.2: Using code in the perspective factory

In the `IPerspectiveFactory`, we do have access to the `IPageLayout`, which happens to be `org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.ModeledPageLayout` (e4 stuff).

Now, this `ModeledPageLayout` implementation is reasonable, but also no documentation and weird public APIs. This one gives the possibility to stack a view over any other relative

```
modeledPageLayout.stackView("newView0", IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
```

This would be the programmatic version of **2.1**. Also, the same problem appears here. If a view is opened somewhere else, the code above becomes useless.

Interesting enough, the `stackView` API does not support wildcards (while others such as `addView` do).

---

### 2.3) Possible fix no.3: Workarounds yaaay!

I have a lot of perspectives, and a lot of different folders in each one. Everything is precisely placed.

Since Eclipse offers the APIs to get all the view IDs from everywhere around the system, I want to do the following, per perspective: **each view ID which wasn't added to a specific folder will be appended to the editor area (ie editor folder, editor stack)**.

This would be my last resort, unless someone offers a more convenient and timesaving solution.

Remember, an e4 programmatic alternative is more flexible!

---

### 3.) Related questions

- [Eclipse RCP -- Open View in Editor folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382848/eclipse-rcp-open-view-in-editor-folder)
- [Eclipse  RCP - Stacking a view with the editor area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758642/eclipse-rcp-stacking-a-view-with-the-editor-area)
- [Custom Eclipse perspective, with initially invisble view stacked to editor area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921306/custom-eclipse-perspective-with-initially-invisble-view-stacked-to-editor-area)
- [Google question, Lars answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vogella/_2yEZMg8epk)

These would be rendered deprecated for the e4 release.

---

### 4.) Related Bug on Eclipse's Bugzilla:

[This recent bug opened by myself](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=450854) has an attachment with a small SSCCE. The steps to reproduce this are described in [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=450854#c2), so I'm not going to copy-paste them here.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that this can be done when the 3.x compatibility code is included. You might be able to place a view in the editor area using the e4 APIs but I would expect that to confuse the compatibility code.

Comment: If you don't use any editors, then simply minimize the shared area and design the layout as you want it.

Comment: move forward to a more recent version where this works out of the box.

Comment: @bebbo I do use editors, and I can't move the whole thing to e4 at once. Enterprise software. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go with Possible fix no.3, since i think there isn't a faster method to do this.

Comment: any suggestion with pripr answer could be wriiten as a comment instead of a new answer.